# NGINX error: 404 on a Node.js backend app, the frontend is working fine

Tags: node.js, nginx, http-status-code-404, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm really new to all of this, I have been trying to mount a web app with a React frontend and a Node.js backend on a Ubuntu 20.04.6 server. I'm using NGINX to redirect to the files. I have an ufw firewall with the ports 443 and 80 opened through OpenSSH and Nginx Full prompts.

I'm trying to have everything under a single domain, the backend on /api.

Everything is alright with the frontend on name.io, it's reaching the client without problems. But accesing the backend using name.io/api/users returns a 404. When the node app is not running it returns a 502, so it's responding. I have alredy read a lot and tried different things but haven't been able to solve this.

With the small knowledge I have, I think the problem is somewhere in the nginx config. This is my default file in sites-available on Nginx:

```
server {

  server_name name.io www.name.io;

root /home/user/name-build;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/name.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/name.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.name.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = name.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;

  server_name name.io www.name.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

And this is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const cors = require('cors');

const AppError = require('./utils/appError');
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/errorController');
const { usersRoute } = require('./routes/users');
const { requestLogger, errorLogger } = require('./middlewares/logger');
const limiter = require('./middlewares/rateLimit');
require('dotenv').config();

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCPETION... app cerrándose');
  console.log(err.name, err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});

const { PORT = 3000, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/name');
app.use(helmet());

app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(requestLogger);

app.use(mongoSanitize());
const whitelist = ['https://name.io', 'https://www.name.io'];
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
    }
  },
};
app.use(cors({ corsOptions }));
app.use(xss());

app.get('/crash-test', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error('El servidor va a apagarse');
  }, 0);
});

app.use(limiter);
app.use('api/users', usersRoute);

app.use(errorLogger);

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`No se encuentra ${req.originalUrl} en el servidor`, 404));
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(NODE_ENV, PORT);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  console.log('UNHANDLED REJECTION... app cerrándose');
  console.log(err.name, err.message, err);
  server.close(() => {
    process.exit(1);
  });
});
```

I have alredy restarted everything: pm2, nginx, ufw. Also I have been trying little changes on the nginx sites-available default document.
Also, the 404 that happens is not the 404 that I have writed on app.js, the error probably comes from Nginx.

Comment: I resolved it adding  "proxy_redirect off;" to location /api/ and also, looking at the error logs the /api route was redirecting to my backend so it was callint to localhost:3000/users but in the backend I was using the route /api/users.